# Text in <textarea> automatically getting tabbed in

Tags: php, html, mysql

pretty new to Mysql, HTML and PHP and I can't seem to find much information on this trouble i'm having.

I Am making my own rough project manager type thing and I have a form that lets me change the contents of each individual change log, the problem I have however is that when I load the data in to the text area it start with a big indentation at the start, like 3-4 tabs inwards. I would attach an image but I need at least 10 rep to do that.

Basically, it feels like the data in the database has tabs or something at the start of it, but when I go to look in PHPmyadmin at the field, it just looks like it should do, not tabbed at all.

I've tried using strip_tags() but I think it only works on visible tags.

Does any1 know how to get rid of this or what is causing the problem?

I'll be following this question closely to see if anybody  can provide an answer because I'm stumped.

Thanks,

Comment: You have tabs inside the textarea. Check your php code, and you will see

Comment: Some html and php code regarding the textfield please.

Comment: There is no need to. I think. By the description, he has something like `<textarea> <?php code here ?> </textarea>` and is asking why the whitespace.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel You are completely right, My code is -      <textarea name="changelog" rows="6" cols="50">'.strip_tags($ChangeLog).'</textarea>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to echo your php code with no blanks :

Possible tabs, bad example :

```
<textarea>
     <?php echo $tabContent; ?>
</textarea>
```

Avoiding tabs :

```
<textarea><?php echo $tabContent; ?></textarea>
```

You can also try to trim your php content like that :

```
<textarea><?php echo trim($tabContent); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Ah thank you for this! I had the variable echoing on another line, didn't think text area would also include tab indents that were done in Notepad++

Comment: I will accept your answer after the timer has expired :)

Comment: You're welcome, it's a common mistake I think, everybody did it once!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing var_dump and look how long your queried string is.
If it is as long as in your database you problem is within the textarea.
Is there any css you use with textarea?

Comment: var_dump just shows this - string(28) "This is just another test. "